# Pytorch: How to load all images of a folder in a batch?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

The structure of the data is as follows:

```
data
├── 209109
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.png
│   ├── 3.png
│   └── 4.png
├── 217707
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.png
│   ├── 3.png
│   └── 4.png
├── 2179695
│   ├── 1.png
│   ├── 2.png
│   ├── 3.png
│   └── 4.png
...
```

Suppose `batch_size=4`, and I want to load images as `for idx,data in enumerate(tqdm(dataloader))`.

When `idx=0`, `data` contains all images in folder `209109`;

When `idx=1`, `data` contains all images in folder `217707`;

When `idx=2`, `data` contains all images in folder `2179695`.

Is this possible? If so, how to define the `Dataset` and `Dataloader`? Thanks!

Furthermore, whether such a dataloader can be implemented：

When `idx=0`, `data` is [209109/1.png, 217707/1.png, ...];

When `idx=1`, `data` is [209109/2.png, 217707/2.png, ...];

When `idx=2`, `data` is [209109/3.png, 217707/3.png, ...].

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote some codes to print the path of the files, no need to use `idx`:

```
import os
path_data = r"D:\data" # Here is your path 
for dir_name, _, file_list in os.walk(path_data):
    for file in file_list:
        if file :
            print(os.path.join(dir_name, file)) # Instead of print, you can do your stuff here.
```

And then I got the result :

```
D:\data\209109\1.png
D:\data\209109\2.png
D:\data\209109\3.png
D:\data\209109\4.png
D:\data\217707\1.png
D:\data\217707\2.png
D:\data\217707\3.png
D:\data\217707\4.png
D:\data\2179695\1.png
D:\data\2179695\2.png
D:\data\2179695\3.png
D:\data\2179695\4.png
```

The code will walk through all the files, respecting the order of the folders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! yes, you're right. And I wander if I can use torch.utils.data.DataLoader?